# How to get two elements in a <div> to call different functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Im new to javascript/html/css so excuse me if this seems like a simple question, but I'm building an overlay on a page and there are two elements with onclick functions.

```
<div id="calibration" class="overlay">

  <a href="#" class="closeBtn" onclick="closeCalibration()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" class="calDot" onclick="moveCalibrationDot()">&bull;</a>

  <div class="overlay__content">
    <a href="#">Please look at the red dots and click on them as they appear.</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Both elements however seem to call the same functions instead of two different functions as they're supposed to. The two functions being,

```
document.getElementById('calibration').style.height = "100%";


function closeCalibration() {
  document.getElementById('calibration').style.height = "0%";
}

function moveCalibrationDot() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

Here's a link to a jsfiddle if that is helpful, https://jsfiddle.net/mnc8m3tr/2/

And the css I'm using is,

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;

background: rgba(1, 1, 1, .9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay__content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.overlay .closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.overlay .calDot {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have 2 `<a>` elements inside a `<div>` element calling diferent functions... Where is the problem?

Comment: That fiddle seems to be broken - see [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QhLyTexVHAddk6HTXgl1?p=preview)

Comment: @SrAxi The problem is that the second anchor overlaps the first making the first impossible to click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is appearing over the "x" link because of it's positioning, so you're clicking the dot whenever you click the "x". Make the dot `position: absolute;` and it will not overlap the other button.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, .9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay__content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.overlay .closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.overlay .calDot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calibration" class="overlay">

  <a href="#" class="closeBtn" onclick="closeCalibration()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" class="calDot" onclick="moveCalibrationDot()">&bull;</a>

  <div class="overlay__content">
    <a href="#">Please look at the red dots and click on them as they appear.</a>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('calibration').style.height = "100%";


  function closeCalibration() {
    document.getElementById('calibration').style.height = "0%";
  }

  function moveCalibrationDot() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Open your jsfiddle and then DevTools in chrome (by F12).
Then inspect your buttons and you will see that one of your links is very wide and covers close button.

Comment: Was about to post this! You were quicker. :P  +1